# How to convert timestamp to actual Date and Time with GMT timezone

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have a timestamp which is like this

```
$timestamp = time();
```

so the `$timestamp` has `10` digit `timestamp` value...

now i use the follwoing code to convert it into `(YYYY-mm-dd H:i)` format by the following method

```
$act_time = date('Y-m-d H:i', $arr_timestamp);
```

But now i want to convert it based on the GMT timezone format..
How can i achieve that?

```
NOTE: I dont want to use php's DateTime object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php):

```
date_default_timezone_set("GMT");
```

List of [Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

You can save the current timezone before changing it:

```
$backupTimezone = date_default_timezone_get();
```

In addition, instead of using these you can change the default timezone in your ini file: `date.timezone`